# AddingViewcontroller manually into the stack swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am coding the sign out button in my app.This is the flow of my app.

1. `SplashvwController` -> `secretCodeViewController` ->
   `LoginviewController` -> `DashboardViewController`

in this `DashboardViewController` I have the signOut button.

My app has single sign in facility once user logged, next time when he opens the app,

2. `SplashvwController` -> `DashboardViewController`

I want to prompt the user to `Loginviewcontroller` whenever he clicks the sign out button.

**Question**

When user going through path 1 I can simply do `popviewcontroller` to go back to the previous viewcontroller. But when user go though the 2nd path,

- how can I add the `Loginviewcontroller` manually into my
  viewcontrollers stack to perform the same operation?
- How can I check whether the LoginviewController exists in my current Viewcontrollers stack?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think, the below code helps you,

```
 for (var i = 0; i < self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count; i++) {
                        if(self.navigationController?.viewControllers[i].isKindOfClass(Loginviewcontroller) == true) {

                            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[i], animated: true)

                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

> To add a ViewController Manually , check the code below..

```
     let navigation = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController 
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: navigation) 
appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = nav
```

Comment: In the log out button action , you can add this `let navigation = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
                            
                            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: navigation)
                            appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = nav`

Comment: and declare `let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate` and `let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`
globally

Answer (score 0):

Set the storyboard reference `identifier` for a `LoginViewController` on the `Main.Storyboard` file.

Whenever you want to show the `LoginViewController` just call the function

```
  func launchLoginView() {
        if let loginVC: LoginViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginStoryboardID") as? LoginViewController {

        // .instantiatViewControllerWithIdentifier() returns AnyObject! this must be downcast to utilize it
       // LoginStoryboardID is the reference id for login view controller.


            self.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil). 
            // OR
            //UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = loginVC
        }
    }
```

**Landing screen based on the User login status.**

In `AppDelegte.swift`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            let isLoggedAlready = //Get the login status
             if isLoggedAlready == true {
                if let dashBoardVC: DashboardViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardStoryboardID") as? DashboardViewController {
                     //Already logged in then directly launch dashboard vc.

                    //change the code based on your needs
                      window?.rootViewController =  dasbBoardVC

                }
             } 
        // Otherwise let it go as flow 1

        return true

   } 
}
```

Comment: Can I add it as 2nd view controller? Not the root view controller?

Comment: Yes, you can.. Check the login status and push @user1960169

Comment: No I mean now you have set it as root controller haven't you? So I want to insert it after my splashViewcontroller. My root viewcontroller always should be the spaslviewcontroller. (this is not the default launching file)

Comment: Okay. Then add the logic status check on your Splashview controller. Don't change window.rootViewController. In Splashviewcontroller before pushing to secret code view controller check the login status if already logged in then don't go to secret code view, push to dashboard view